# Unable to send the updated value of state through props in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to send state value from parent to child component.Initially the state value is empty.After an API call,state value get updated but my props is taking the initial empty value.

```
class Metrics extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.state.result:[];
}

  submit = e => {
     e.preventDefault();
    var URL =
     "http://localhost:8080/fetchAnalysisData;
    this.setState({ formsubmit: true });

    fetch(URL, {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Response Success!!");
        this.setState({ result: data });
      });
  };

render(){
return(

<Button onClick={this.submit}
                   fontSize: "small",
                    marginLeft: "30%"
                  }}
                >
                  VIEW RESULT
                </Button>
<div className={this.state.formsubmit ? "showDisplay" : "hide"}>
 <DipslayBarChart result={this.state.result}></DipslayBarChart>
</div>
)
}
```

Child Component:

```
class DipslayBarChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
              <BarChart width={500} height={300} data={this.props.result}>
                      <XAxis dataKey="Date" />
                      <YAxis />
                      <Tooltip cursor={false} />
                      <Legend />
                      <Bar dataKey="Success" stackId="a" fill="#068f12" label />
                      <Bar
                        dataKey="Failure"
                        stackId="a"
                        fill="#ec0b0b"
                      />
                    </BarChart>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

How to update the prop value once the state is updated?

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(data) instead of console.log("Response success!")?

Comment: It has updated value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your constructor like this,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      result:[]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moreover If you are not using the props in the constructor no need to declare constructor. you can declare state like this

```
state={
  result:[]
}
```